# How to pass multiple columns to replaceColumn! at once?

Tags: alter-table, dolphindb

I want to change the data type of specific columns with `replaceColumn!`. But I can only pass one column at a time to the function.

How to change the data types of multiple columns with just one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DolphinDB, `replaceColumn!(table,colName,newCol)` supports changing the data type of only one column, because the parameter *colName* is designed as a string scalar.

To replace multiple columns at once with `replaceColumn!`, use `each`:  `each(replaceColumn!{t}, [col1, col2...], [newcol1, newcol2...])`.